# How to set shape attribute of clr-icon

Tags: clarity, vmware-clarity

I am using `<clr-icon shape=""/>`. I would like to make its `shape` dynamic. If I specify `<clr-icon [shape]="shapeValue"/>` it throws an error shape is not a known property of `clr-icon`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is not really a function of clarity, it's because the component `clr-icon` makes use of the [shape HTML attribute](https://html.com/attributes/area-shape/) without declaring it an `@Input` (it's not an angular component, it's a [WebComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Web_Components))

To be able to set an HTML attribute dynamically, you have to use a special format, `[attr.shape]` so that Angular will not look for an `@Input` property.

See https://plnkr.co/edit/8qepCA9kgaQejzwXdp5H?p=preview